# C# Console Application, search for matching string[] from two text files

Tags: c#

I have two text files: animal.txt that has

```
number,letter,color,animal
1,a,green,alligator
2,b,brown,bear
3,c,black,cat
4,d,white,dog
5,e,pink,elephant
```

and habit.txt that has

```
colour,animal,found,diet
green,alligator,swamp,fish
green,alligator,swamp,bird
brown,bear,forest,fruit
black,cat,home,catfood
white,dog,home,dogfood
pink,elephant,space,spacefruit
```

My code so far asks for a number and a letter. and searches the text file using string[] and split.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string number;
        string letter;
        bool lineFound = false;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
            number = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter letter");
            letter = Console.ReadLine();

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("animal.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(',');
                if ((number == words[1]) && (letter == words[0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    lineFound = true;
                }

                counter++;
            }

            if (!lineFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number and/or letter");
            }

            file.Close();

        }
            while (!lineFound);
```

depending on the input it'll display the line with color and animal.
How do I make it so that it will search another file, habit.txt for matching lines found in animal.txt. for example input can be '1' and 'a' the console will display

```
green,alligator,swamp,fish
green,alligator,swamp,bird
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Contains("some text")
```

I recommend to use a database for you to script desired data rather than a .text file that stands up like a long strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string number;
        string letter;
        // this assumes that there will always be only one record??
        bool lineFound;

        string animalType = null;
        string animalColor = null;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
            number = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter letter");
            letter = Console.ReadLine();

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("animal.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(',');
                // your example data shows the number in position 0 and the letter in position 1
                if ((number == words[0]) && (letter == words[1]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                    // assign the found animals type and color to use later

                    animalType = words[3];
                    animalColor = words[2];

                    lineFound = true;
                }

                counter++;
            }

            if (!lineFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number and/or letter");
            }

            file.Close();

            System.IO.StreamReader habitatFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("habitat.txt");
            // line is being used by two different streams and can create unexpected behavior so instead create a seperate variable
            while ((line = habitatFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(',');
                // your example data shows the number in position 0 and the letter in position 1
                if ((animalColor == words[0]) && (animalType == words[1]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            habitatFile.Close();
        }
        while (!lineFound);
    }
}
```

But I would consider looking at making these line of text into classes and seeing what things you can make easier (for example, what if you can search instead for animals by color?)

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Letter { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    // CSV file has listed as 'animal'
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Habitat
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    // CSV file has listed as 'animal'
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Found { get; set; }

    public string Diet { get; set; }

}
```